# Open an account in Google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have to publish my app in Google Play Store. And I'm from India having a account in State Bank Of India and i have a debit card. But Google play store not accepting this card saying invalid card number and I have visited many website and found the concept of virtual visa card  through [entropay](https://www.entropay.com/) but it is not working.

If any one have any ideas about it with existing bank card. Then guide me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google not accepting Debit Cards from india except card of ICICI bank .

visit http://bigknol.com/open-blog/2013/05/google-wallet-india-debit-card/ . or you can use Credit Card if possible. I have used credit card to create account in play store.

Answer (score 2):

In India only ICICI Debit card is Accepted. You can Ask Your Friends or in Family. 
I would recommend you to use Credit Card.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to borrow credit card from Your friends

or try paypal

indian debit cards wont work ..i tried a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try Entropay. Create an account and create a virtual card. You can then use your debit card or net banking to load the amount.